# how can get rid of duplicate icons on app list?

Tags: lightdm

I installed unity, I enabled lightDm due to some reasons I uninstalled and disabled lightdm after that I get 2 icons for every application. please look the screenshot
look at unreal and google chrome, this is happening to all applications.
[image: screen shot of image]

Comment: Is it possible that at some stage you installed these applications twice? Once via apt and then perhaps via snap? Type `apt list --installed` and look for duplicates then let us know.

Comment: No, I haven't installed twice,  checked  it using the command there is one application named google chrome.

Comment: OK then confirm you are using lightdm by typing `ls /usr/bin/*session` then try this `sudo dpkg -reconfigure gdm3` and reboot. Then to go back to lightdm and see if it is fixed type `sudo apt-get install --reinstall lightdm ubuntu-desktop` and check for duplicate icons again.